# Sorting array of objects in Redux reducer

Tags: javascript, reactjs, sorting, redux, jsx

I am trying to sort an array like this (my state):

```js
[
  {
    name:"Aenean in justo ante"
  },
  {
    name:"Phasellus viverra mattis dolor"
  }
]
```

I dispatch an action to the reducer: (part of reducer)

```js
case 'SORT_COLLECTION':
  return state.sort(function(a, b) {
    var nameA = a.name.toLowerCase(), nameB = b.name.toLowerCase();
    if (nameA < nameB) {
      return -1;
    }
    if (nameA > nameB) {
      return 1;
    }
    return 0;
  })
```

but it does not work.
Could somebody tell me where the mistake is?

Comment: Sort will mutate the array there

Comment: Reducer **should not** mutate a state. It must return a new state object and leave the previous one untouched. If you want to have sorting option, you have to add respective property (e.g. specifying sorting direction) to your state and sort data in `render()` depending on that property's value.

Comment: What exactly do you mean by "it doesnt work". This code doesn't contain any obvious bugs.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

The sorting function should work fine. But you should not mutate the original state in the reducer. You can create a copy of the `state` array by calling `state.slice()` before sorting.

```
case 'SORT_COLLECTION':
  return state.slice().sort(function(a, b) {
    var nameA = a.name.toLowerCase(),
      nameB = b.name.toLowerCase()
    if (nameA < nameB)
      return -1
    if (nameA > nameB)
      return 1
    return 0
  })
```

Of course, you can define a simpler sort function as well.

```js
const state = [{name:'foo'},{name:'bar'},{name:'baz'}]
const sortByKey = key => (a, b) => a[key] > b[key] ? 1 : -1
const sorted = state.slice().sort(sortByKey('name'))
console.log(`state=${JSON.stringify(state)}\nsorted=${JSON.stringify(sorted)}`)
```

Comment: Array.slice does not do a deep copy, hence if you have a nested data structure you're still referencing original state

Comment: @JoeSeifi Yes. The state of the child objects has not changed, only their order. There's no reason to prefer deep copying here.

Answer (score 4):

You need to do:

```
state.slice().sort(...
```

As `sort()` changes the original array by reordering references (mutates it) which is a "no go" for redux store. `slice()` first does a shallow copy meaning only references are copied and it is fast (unless it contains primitives in which case they will be copied, but it will still be fast) and then those new references are moved around by `sort()`.

NOTE: you still can not change the objects within the array, but luckily sort does not change them.

Answer (score 0):

if you are using es6 you can try like this
`state.sort((a,b) => a.name - b.name);`

Answer (score 0):

The [`Array.prototype.sort`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/sort) method requires you to return an `integer` or a `boolean`.

The below shows how to order in either direction.

```js
var arr = [
        {
            name:"Aenean jon justo ante"
        },
        {
            name:"Aenean in justo ante"
        },
        {
            name:"Phasellus viverra mattis dolor"
        }
]

console.log("Alphabetical:", arr.sort((a,b) => a.name > b.name));
console.log("Reversed:", arr.sort((a,b) => a.name < b.name));
```

Comment: Have you read the article you linked? `compareFunction` may return _any number_, not `true` or `false`.